# Why can't pass the variable's value into file in /etc directory?

Tags: bash, variables

I want to pass the value of the `$ip` variable into the file `/etc/test.json` with bash.

```sh
ip="xxxx"
sudo bash -c 'cat > /etc/test.json <<EOF
    {
        "server":"$ip",
     }
EOF'
```

I expect the content of `/etc/test.json` to be

```
{
    "server":"xxxx",
 }
```

However the real content in `/etc/test.json` is:

```
{
    "server":"",
 }
```

But if I replace the target directory `/etc/` with `/tmp`

```sh
ip="xxxx"
cat > /tmp/test.json <<EOF
    {
        "server":"$ip",
    }
EOF
```

the value of the `$ip` variable gets passed into `/tmp/test.json`:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.json
{
    "server":"xxxx",
 }
```

In [Kamil Cuk's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamil-cuk) example, the subprocess is `cat > /etc/test.json` which contains no variable.

```sh
sudo sh -c 'cat > /etc/test.json' << EOF
    {
        "server":"$ip",
    }
EOF
```

It does not export the `$ip` variable at all.

Now let's make an analysis for the following:

```sh
ip="xxxx"
sudo bash -c "cat > /etc/test.json <<EOF
    {
        "server":\""$ip"\",
     }
EOF"
```

The different parts in

```
"cat > /etc/test.json <<EOF
    {
        "server":\""$ip"\",
     }
EOF"
```

will concatenate into a long string and as a command .Why can the `$ip` variable inherit the value from its father process here?

Comment: Shell variables are not expanded in single quotes.

Comment: Use a tool like `jq` to generate JSON, rather than string interpolation (which risks quoting errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons for this behavior:

1. Per default, variables are no passed to the environment of subsequently executed commands.
2. The variable is not expanded in the current context, because your command is wrapped in single quotes.

### Exporting the variable

Place an `export` statement before the variable, see [man 1 bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> The supplied names are marked for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands.

And as noted by [Léa Gris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7939871/l%c3%a9a-gris) you also need to tell sudo to preserve the environment with the `-E` or `--preserve-environment` flag.

```sh
export ip="xxxx"
sudo -E bash -c 'cat > /etc/test.json <<EOF
    {
        "server":"$ip",
     }
EOF'
```

### Expand the variable in the current context:

This is the reason your second command works, you do not have any quotes around the here document in this example.

> But if I replace the target directory `/etc/` with `/tmp` [...] the value of the `$ip` variable gets passed into `/tmp/test.json`

---

You can change your original snippet by replacing the single quotes with double quotes and escaping the quotes around your ip:

```sh
ip="xxxx"
sudo bash -c "cat > /etc/test.json <<EOF
    {
        "server":\""$ip"\",
     }
EOF"
```

**Edit:** For your additional questions:

> In Kamil Cuk's example, the subprocess is cat > /etc/test.json which contains no variable.
>
> ```sh
> sudo sh -c 'cat > /etc/test.json' << EOF
>     {
>         "server":"$ip",
>     }
> EOF
> ```
>
> It does not export the `$ip` variable at all.

Correct and you did not wrap the here document in single quotes. Therefore `$ip` is substituted in the current context and the string passed to subprocesses standard input is

```
{
    "server":"xxxx",
}
```

So in this example the subprocess does not need to know the `$ip` variable.

### Simple example

```
$ x=1
$ sudo -E sh -c 'echo $x'
[sudo] Password for kalehmann:
```

This echos nothing because

- `'echo $x'` is wrapped in single quotes. `$x` is therefore not substituted in the current context
- `$x` is not exported. Therefore the subprocess does not know its value.

```
$ export y=2
$ sudo -E sh -c 'echo $y'
[sudo] Password for kalehmann:
2
```

This echos **2** because

- `'echo $y'` is wrapped in single quotes. `$x` is therefore not substituted in the current context
- `$y` is exported. Therefore the subprocess does know its value.

```
$ z=3
$ sudo -E sh -c "echo $z"
[sudo] Password for kalehmann:
3
```

This echos **3** because

- `"echo $z"` is wrapped in double quotes. `$z` is therefore substituted in the current context

Comment: Isn't `sudo --preserve-env=ip bash -c 'stuffs_with "$ip"'` required to pass the ip as environment variable to the bash running as sudo?

Comment: please give a detail explanation for my added puzzle.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature I have updated my answer. It are not the single quotes around the subprocess, that are important, but the ones around the here document

Comment: @LéaGris yes you are right, this is needed in my first example

Answer (score 0):

There little need to do the here document inside the subshell. Just do it outside.

```
sudo tee /etc/test.json <<EOF
    {
        "server":"$ip",
    }
EOF
```

or

```
sudo sh -c 'cat > /etc/test.json' << EOF
    {
        "server":"$ip",
    }
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is not safe to build a fragment of JSON using string interpolation, because it requires you to ensure the variables are properly encoded. Let a tool like `jq` to that for you.

Pass the output of `jq` to `tee`, and use `sudo` to run `tee` to ensure that the *only* thing you do as root is open the file with the correct permissions.

```
ip="xxxx"

jq --arg x "$ip" '{server: $x}' | sudo tee /etc/test.json > /dev/.null
```